# Storing read_chunk and re-running knitr

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am using read_chunk in a rmarkdown document to run an external script.

One of the chunks takes a while to run which makes debugging the rmarkdown document a pain as I press the knitr button in Rstudio and it runs the document from the beginning.
Is there a way of storing the output of chunks and running knitr from a certain point so the debugging can be quicker?

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would help...

Comment: Have you tried turning caching on?

Comment: How did I not know that. Thanks @RomanLustrik. Please post as a an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use caching of chunks by either enabling it for all chunks

```
opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE)
```

or for individual chunk using

````
```{r chunkname, cache = TRUE}
````

See more in the [documentation](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/).